# AWS Lambda Deployment Package minute code change need every time update

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I have built a deployment package with pandas, numpy, etc for my sample code to run. The size is some 46 MB. Doubt is, do I have to zip my code update every time and again update the entire deployment package to AWS S3 for a simple code update too?

Is there any other way, by which, I can avoid the 45 MB upload cost of S3 everytime and just upload the few KBs of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a layer in AWS lambda.

First you need to create an instance of Amazon Linux (using the AMI specified in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html - at this time (26th of March 2019) it is amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2 ) or a docker container with the same environment as the lambda execution environment.

I personally do it with docker.

For example, to create a layer for Python 3.6, I would run

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 bash
```

Then I would create a folder python/lib/python3.6/site-packages in /var/task in the docker container (so it will be accessible later on in the directory on the host machine where I started docker)

do `pip3 install <your packages here> -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

zip up the folder python and upload it as a layer and use it in my AWS lambda function.

**NB! The paths in the zip file should look like "python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/{your package names}"**

Now the heavy dependencies are in separate layer and you don't have re-upload them every time you update the function, you only need to update the code

Comment: I thought of using the newly launched Layer, but the steps are too many and would take a lot of time. Also needs me to install docker which I am not so handy with. Tell me, if I want to avoid using docker, still I have to launch an EC2 for the building part, right? Can I use the smallest, free EC2 micro for this job or would that process cost me something? Is there any other way I can do it with ease/much more simplicity?

Comment: Docker is probably the simplest(it will start up in seconds and run on your machine vs a few minutes with an ec2 instance and connecting remotely with ssh), but if you prefer to use an ec2 instance, even a nano or micro will do. You could write a bash script that would do all of those things automatically once you have done it once manually and corfirmed that you got all the details right. The bash script would work pretty much the same for ec2 and docker, resulting in a usable zip file.

Comment: @AakashBasu If you go the ec2 route, be sure to use the AMI amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2 source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Comment: This is real helpful. Thank you Pärt!

Answer (score 0):

Split the application into two parts. The first part would be the lambda function that only includes your application code. The next part a lambda layer. The lambda layer will include onky the the dependencies and be uploaded once.

A lambda layer can be uploaded and attached to the lambda function. When your function is invoked, AWS will combine the lambda function with the lambda layer then execute the entire package.

When updating your code, you will only need to update the lambda function. Since the package is much smaller you can edit it using the web editor, or you can zip it and upload it directly to lambda using the cli tools.

Exmample:  aws lambda update-function-code --function-name Yourfunctionname --zip-file fileb://Lambda_package.zip

Here are video instructions and examples on creating a lambda layer for dependencies.It demonstrates using the pymsql library, but you can install any of your libraries there.

https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Create_Lambda_Layer_Python